# Convert Date Format from jS \of F Y D to Ymd in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I have date in the following format

`31st of August 2014 Sun` using `$cursor->format("jS \of F Y D");` but how can I convert the existing time to `Ymd` so that the output will be `20140831`

I tried like `echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime(31st of August 2014 Sun));`

and I don't know why the output is showing like 1970 Jan 1 which is weird.

I also tried

```
echo contime('1st of August 2013 Sun');

function contime($gettime) {
$fetch_date = strtotime($gettime);
$date = new DateTime('');
return $date->format('Ymd');
}
```

But this is returning today's date.

Also tried [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

```
$old_date = date('1st of August 2013 Sun');  //date('l, F d y h:i:s'); // returns Saturday, January 30 10 02:06:34
$old_date_timestamp = strtotime($old_date);
$new_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $old_date_timestamp);   
echo $new_date;
```

But its printing `1970-01-01 00:00:00`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("jS \of F Y D", '31st of August 2014 Sun');
echo $date->format('Ymd');
```

But be aware that string must be correct, in your example you have:

```
'1st of August 2013 Sun'
```

where 1st of August 2013 is not sunday, it's shursday, if days names in your data set are not correct you should remove them.

Comment: True, 1st of August is not Sunday. Good catch :)

Answer (score 1):

You should split the time into day month year minute and second (you will need to turn the month into a number) and then you should be able to use mktime:

```
 echo date("Y-m-d", mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year));
```

Comment: Lol, is this the only way? Splitting date from `jS \of F Y D` format will be another big headache. :(